# How to search for github projects by their functionality?

Tags: github, open-source

I am looking for interesting GitHub projects to work on, for example, I am interested in photography and timelapse videos, and I am looking for mac or windows desktop open source apps that will allow me to make time lapse clips.

There doesn't seem to be an advanced feature on GitHub that allows you to search by project functionality, it is only allowing you to search projects by keywords as it seems, or allow you to explore popular trendy project.

Is there a query that would approach what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept of functionality.

The best you can hope for is for said functionality to be mentioned in the `README` of the project, or its description.

See "[Search by repository name, description, or contents of the `README` file](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-by-repository-name-description-or-contents-of-the-readme-file)", and its qualifiers `in:readme` and `in:description`.
For instance:

https://github.com/search?q=jquery+in%3Areadme&type=Repositories

This would match repositories mentioning "`jquery`" in their `README` file.